# how to display 2nd post out of 5 post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display 2nd post out of 5 post in WordPress.

```
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&category=1');
foreach($myposts as $post):
  the_post_thumbnail();
  the_title();
  the_content();
endforeach;
```

Comment: Have you tried `get_posts('numberposts=1&category=1&offset=1')`?

Comment: yes bro. but not working @JonSurrell

Answer (score 0):

you can get the 2nd post (if you always want the 2nd post) with this:

```
$keys = array_keys($myposts);
$secondPost = $myposts[$keys[1]];
```

How to use with wordpress (not test, but should work):

```
$args = [
'category' => '1',
'posts_per_page' => '5'
];
$postArray = get_posts($args);
$keys = array_keys($postArray);
$secondPost = $myposts[$keys[1]];
```

look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts. Where you see the default values. (5 posts per query is default, if you would set it to 2 you could also do:

```
$args = [
'category' => '1',
'posts_per_page' => '2'
];
$postArray = get_posts($args);
$secondPost = end($postArray);
```

but than you get only 2 posts. If that's enough for you, this would also work.)

Comment: <?php
         global $post;
   $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=1&category=1');  
         $keys = array_keys($myposts);
         $secondPost = $myposts[$keys[1]];
   foreach($secondPost as $post) :
   ?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>       


Not Working .. :(

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of foreach loop you can use for loop and write the condition what ever you want. or inside this statement you use if($post==1 && $post==3 && $post==4 && $post==5){echo" ";}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the array you can save runtime and just `array_shift()` the first element away:

```
$poss = get_posts('numberposts=2');
$post = array_shift($posts);
print_r($post);
```